# using Zapier to send XML to a URL

Tags: xml, zapier, fulfillment

i'm trying to send an XML code to a fulfillment company through a URL (https://import.checkout-secured.com/bo/interface/order/import) using Zapier's POST method.

the fulfillment company says they are not receiving it.

can someone please point me to the right direction? what am i'm doing wrong?

here's the XML code...

```
<sales>
 <sale>
    <cid>615</cid>
    <apikey>asdf1234</apikey>
    <miscID>morpheuzG</miscID>
    <email>morpheuzG@gmail.com</email>

    <bill>
       <contact>
          <fname>MorpheuZ</fname>
          <lname>Gee</lname>
       </contact>

       <address>
          <line1>123 Main St.</line1>
          <line2></line2>
          <city>New York</city>
          <state>NY</state>
          <zip>10007</zip>
          <country>USA</country>
       </address>
    </bill>

    <orderDate>03/24/2020 01:01:01 AM</orderDate>

    <items>
       <item>
          <sku>10101010</sku>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
       </item>
    </items>

    <ship>
       <method>Shipping</method>
    </ship>

    <billInstructions>Test 1</billInstructions>
    <shipInstructions>Test Ship 1</shipInstructions>
 </sale>
</sales>
```

Zapier details:

```
Method: Post
URL: https://import.checkout-secured.com/bo/interface/order/import
Data-Pass Through: (blank)
Date: (shown above)
Unflatten: No
Basic Auth: (blank)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the code above, but you can find some clues when you're logged in to Zapier. Here are some tips that might help:

First, you can try looking at your Task History at https://zapier.com/app/history. Each time your Zap runs, you'll see a row in the history here. If you find a timestamp corresponding to a Zap that you think should have worked, you can click on that row and see the results from each step. For example, if there was an error, or a piece of missing data, you'll see that status in the Task History. If the Zap "worked," you can look into the data to see what was sent and debug that way. https://zapier.com/learn/getting-started-guide/task-history/

If that still doesn't work, the Zapier customer service team can dig in farther to give you some advice. Head to https://zapier.com/app/contact-us and add some context; they can dig in further and help you figure this out.

Comment: thank you for your answer...

actually, i'm doing a test zap and asking the fulfillment company to verify if they received the test. and they say they are not receiving it. so i'm not sure where i did wrong. 

i have not set it to LIVE yet.

Comment: also, i contacted Zapier support about it and they just pointed me to here in case someone can help me.

Comment: You'll probably need to turn on the Zap before it starts sending real data, unless this is the final step in the Zap. Data from the earlier steps are usually simulated. Also, I'm surprised that you would be sent here from Zapier's customer support! I work at Zapier, and we don't redirect people to other forums. We try to solve all of the problems through our own help service. :) Feel free to write back with a link to your example Zap, and we can take a closer look--you can point to this conversation too.

Comment: the POST XML is the final step of the Zap. 

it's really weird they pointed me here. i am replying to their email reply to me.